# public good contribution game theory

Tags: game-theory

Public Good Contribution: Three players live in a town, and each can choose
to contribute to fund a streetlamp. The value of having the streetlamp is 3 for
each player, and the value of not having it is 0. The mayor asks each player to
contribute either 1 or nothing. If at least two players contribute then the lamp
will be erected. If one player or no players contribute then the lamp will not
be erected, in which case any person who contributed will not get his money
back.

a. Write out or graph each player’s best-response correspondence.

b. What outcomes can be supported as pure-strategy Nash equilibria?

Consider player $i$ with beliefs about the choices of players $j$ and $k$. If neither $j$ nor $k$ contribute then player $i$ does not want to contribute because the lamp would not be erected and he would lose his contribution. Similarly, if both $j$ and $k$ contribute then player $i$ does not want to contribute because the lamp would be erected without his contribution so he can free ride on their contributions. The remaining cases is where only one of the players $j$ and $k$ contribute, in which case by contributing $1$ player $i$ receives $2$, while by not contributing he receives $0$, and hence contributing is a best response. In summary,

$BR_i(s_j,s_k)=\begin{cases} 0 , \text{ if $s_i=s_j$}\\1 ,\text{ if $s_k=1$ or $s_j=1$}\end{cases}$

Would this be correct for (a)?

for (b) :

The best response correspondence described in (a) above implies that there are two kinds of Nash equilibria: one kind (which is unique) is where no player contributes, and the other kind has two of the three players contributing and the third free riding. Hence, either the lamp being erected with two players contributing or the lamp not being erected with no player contributing can be supported as Nash equilibria.

Comment: The upper line of the rhs of your best response function contains a typo, it should be $s_k=s_j$. The lower line should be an exclusive "or". You could write the rhs in a single line as $|s_k-s_j|$. However, I think they are actually asking for $i$'s best response correspondence on $[0,1]^2$, not just $\{0,1\}^2$, i.e. including mixed strategies.

Comment: ... and pls correct the first word of the title! ;)